# Option to select download location when "always open with system viewer" in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, adobe-acrobat

When downloading pdfs and viewing them with system viewer (e.g. acrobat), in chrome, you either:

1. Opt out "always open with system viewer", then for each download you get to choose the download location. But you have to manually right-click and choose to open with system viewer. Few more clicks and time wasted.
2. Tick "always open with system viewer", in which case after download it will automatically open in system viewer. However, chrome won't ask you where to download, and the file will go to system default download location.

Is there a way to make chrome ask you the download location each time, and after download complete it automatically open system viewer?

(I get it, google wants to quietly force users to use chrome pdf viewers rather than acrobat. Please do not recommend using chrome built-in pdf viewer. Please also do not recommend using acrobat plugin.)

Comment: You can change the default download folder to your choice.  And try a download manager extension.